# Updating data in firebase when deleting a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `UITableView` and I'm using the commit editingStyle function to remove a cell when swiping left. The problem is when I do that it deletes the right data in firebase, but then it updates it again and the app crashes. This is what I got.

[image: Firebase, before]
[image: Firebase, after]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let taskToDelete = groupTask[indexPath.row]
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        groupTask.remove(at: indexPath.row)
       DataService.instance.REF_GROUPS.child(group!.key).child("task").child(taskToDelete.id).removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, refer) in
            if error != nil {

            } else {

            }
        })
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
    }
}
```

I also have a function when you tap on a cell it updates a child in firebase and then shows an image. It might be that function that is causing the crash:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? GroupTaskCell else { return }

    if cell.isSelected == true {
        let selected = groupTask[indexPath.row]
        DataService.instance.REF_GROUPS.observe(.value) { (snapShot) in
            DataService.instance.updateTaskStatus(desiredGroup: self.group!, selected: true, childPath: selected.id, handler: { (complete) in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    } else {

    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func updateTaskStatus(desiredGroup: Group, selected: Bool, childPath: String, handler: @escaping (_ taskArray: [Task]) -> ()) {

    REF_GROUPS.child(desiredGroup.key).child("task").child(childPath).updateChildValues(["selected": selected])
    }
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should mark
`self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)` with `self.tableView.beginUpdates()` and `self.tableView.endUpdates()`

So it should be something like this

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

And make sure you are not reloading the data right away because it will cause a crash. I don't think you should reload data at all, just make sure that the cell is deleted from the tableView and the data from Firebase and that should be enough. You can reload the tableView the next time you retrieve data or present the tableView

Comment: I tried that but still having the same problem. Any other ides?

Comment: What are you trying to do on didSelectCellForRow? Are you reloading the data or presenting a new view?

Comment: I'm updating a child in firebase. See the pictures at the beginning (links)